# Parsing wrapped objects in JSON with Moshi

Tags: json, kotlin, moshi

I'm trying to parse response from Google Places API with moshi. I only want to get `name` and `location`. Json looks like this:

```
 {
        "geometry": {
            "location": {
                "lat": 51.1167056,
                "lng": 17.0260999
            },
            "viewport": {
                "northeast": {
                    "lat": 51.1180545802915,
                    "lng": 17.0274488802915
                },
                "southwest": {
                    "lat": 51.1153566197085,
                    "lng": 17.0247509197085
                }
            }
        },       
        "name": "name of this place"            
    }
```

I omitted most of elements for better readability. I' ve got problem to parse "lat", "lng" from "location", because it isn't in the base scope. And i don't want to create class for every object, because i don't need them. Is there any easy way to set some attribute to properties to tell moshi where it can find them?

I found [moshi-lazy-adapters](https://github.com/serj-lotutovici/moshi-lazy-adapters) library, but i'm not sure how to use it properly

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you're saying you'd like the option to run dynamic JSON path queries against a given JSON structure, retrieving only the required fields.

That sounds similar to what the awesome CLI tool [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) provides.

Well, if you can access the raw response string directly - there you go https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath.